Execute a stored procedure (V2) with parameter does not return a value
When I execute the following stored procedure through Power Automate, nothing is returned, but if I copy and execute the same query that was sent to the server (using Profiler to capture it) the Id is returned.
(The procedure name and parameter names have been altered for the example, but the code is otherwise identical).
ALTER   PROC [APP].[GetRecordId]
           @GUID uniqueidentifier = null,
           @RecordId int OUTPUT
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    SELECT TOP 1 @RecordId = Id 
        FROM APP.SpecialTable
        WHERE RecordGUID = @GUID;
    RETURN;
GO


{
  "ResultSets": {},
  "ReturnCode": 0,
  "OutputParameters": {}
}

I've tried executing the same query using an Execute A SQL Query (V2) using a SELECT tested in Azure Data Studio, executing the same SPROC, and verified that the account used has the right access privileges.
A different stored procedure that INSERTS new records consistently returns the Inserted.Id using a similar OUTPUT parameter so I'm not sure why these fail.

I can't see, in that image, that you provide the parameter @RecordId.

@ThomA for other procedures that I've executed in the past couple of years I have never needed to include the output parameter. It's returned and can be accessed as a property of the flow action.

I admit, I don't know Power Automate, but from a T-SQL perspective, to get the value for an output parameter, you first have to pass it a parameter; OUTPUT parameters are actually input and output parameters, and your (local) variable isn't assigned the value of the OUTPUT parameter if you didn't pass it to the procedure. though, your OUTPUT parameter doesn't have a default value, which suggests a variable is being passed to it, as if it were not, it would error.

Yes, you're correct for T-SQL. Power Automate automatically adds the parameter to the request and it typically is returned in the body of the request:
set @p2=NULL
exec APP.GetRecordId @Guid=N'0fc15b03-16c3-482f-bbf2-326535323d5c',@RecordId=@p2 output
select @p2```

Perhaps it has something to do with order of execution? A different sproc looks like this, with the InsertedId assigned to @p32:

```declare @p32 int
set @p32=57978
exec [APP].[InsertRecord] @DonateCarGuid=N'0fc15b03-16c3-482f-bbf2-326535323d5c',....',@InsertedId=@p32 output
select @p32```

Aside: Using TOP 1 without ORDER BY adds the virtual query hint RANDOM_ROW.

@HABO I had no idea, this is appreciated and would affect the desired result. I'll update my query, although it won't solve the main issue it does solve an unexpected one.
